# Insert consecutive numbers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `A` (Acons, A1, A2, A3)  in which I should insert information from another table `B` with columns (B1, B2, B3). The Acons is a column in which should contain some consecutive numbers (it is not an identity and I cannot make it identity). I know  xmin - starting the from number the sequence has to be computed. How can I insert the rows into the table A, using a single Insert statement?

I tried like the following, but it didn't work:

```
DECLARE @i AS INT;

SET @i = xmin;    

INSERT INTO A(Acons, A1, A2, A3)
SELECT @i = (Bcons = (@i + 1)), B1, B2, B3
FROM B
```

Unfortunatelly, the above solution does not work;

Answer (score 3):

You already have a set of rows to generate numbers from to add to Bcons. It's trickier in SQL Server 2000 but one hopes you're on SQL Server 2005 +

```
WITh cNumbers AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Bcons) AS Number,
        Bcons, B1, B2, B3
    FROM
        B
)
INSERT INTO A (Acons, A1, A2, A3)
SELECT
    Bcons + Number /* need -1 here? */, B1, B2, B3
FROM
    cNumbers
```

As Philip Kelley mentioned, we don't need the CTE. Doh.

```
SELECT
    Bcons + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Bcons) /* need -1 here? */, B1, B2, B3
FROM
    B
```

Comment: you are one sick puppy. That's a real nice answer

Comment: I don't think you need the CTE -- it looks like you can have {ROW_NUMBER} + 1 as a column.

Comment: @Philip Kelley: Good point... force of habit even though it's a simple select really

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know from where comes xmin but, try it this.

```
DECLARE @i AS INT;
SET @i = xmin; 
Insert into A
Select @i+1,b1,b2,b3 from B
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it:

```
DECLARE @i AS INT;
SET @i = xmin;
insert into a
select ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b1))+@i) AS Number,b1,b2,b3 from b
```

--Re-edited

Comment: i don't know if that is what you want but, try it.